# Javascript - What is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript

Write a function queue which takes an "array" and an "item" as arguments. Add the item onto the end of the array, then remove the first element of the array. The queue function should return the element that was removed.
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5];

NOte: I only added codes that are in between the asterisk * which means only codes that is in asterisk need to be changed.

```
  function queue(arr, item) {
     // Your code here
     *arr.push(item);
     arr.shift();*

    return *(arr, item)*;  // Change this line
  }

     // Display Code
    console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(myArr));
     console.log(queue(myArr, 1)); // Modify this line to test
     console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(myArr));
```

Comment: You have not even stated what the issues are or what error message you receive.  Also using `*` is not a smart way to mark parts of your code as this symbol has a meaning in javascript (and other c-like languages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript works with pointer, so passing the array as a paramater will edit that array from where it was called.

This should do the job :

```
function queue(arr, item) {
    arr.push(item);
    return arr.shift();
}

var myArr = [1,2,3,4];
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(myArr));
console.log(queue(myArr, 1)); // Modify this line to test
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(myArr));
```

Answer (score 3):

> The queue function should return the element that was removed.

That's what `shift` does, it returns the shifted element

```
function queue(arr, item) {
     arr.push(item);
     return arr.shift();
}
```